# How to ensure that the data traffic is going over the VPN connection?

Tags: wi-fi, vpn

I have Motorola XT910 and I would like to install the Motorola AnyConnect by Cisco to use when out in public and using open WiFi. Once I do that how can I check if all the traffic that is coming from my phone is going over those VPN tunnels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application, [Motorola AnyConnect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.motorola&hl=en), takes care of that for you.

When you sign on to your corporate network, the Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client for Android only allows the traffic thru the VPN Tunnel created, preventing any armful or unauthorized access or data transfer outside the parameters defined by your corporation security policies.

> Cisco AnyConnect provides reliable and easy-to-deploy encrypted network connectivity from Motorola Android devices by delivering persistent corporate access for users on the go.

---

One thing that's not clear on your question is if you're aware that this Cisco solution is a corporate solution, not for the end user who just want's to navigate the web covertly.

> Whether providing access to business email, a virtual desktop session, or most other Android applications, AnyConnect enables business-critical application connectivity. Through the use of Datagram Transport Layer Security (DTLS), TCP-based applications and latency-sensitive traffic (such as voice over IP [VoIP]) are provided an optimized communication path to corporate resources.

**Users have to authenticate to their enterprise networks** in order to use this app and the features provided, **but you can navigate the internet as usual**, only restricted by the security policies applied.

---

Additional Reading about this solution:

- [Motorola AnyConnect from Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.motorola&hl=en)
- [Android User Guide for Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect25/android-user/guide/android-acug.html#wp56848)
- [AnyConnect Secure Mobility Introduction Video from YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfwjQ6TvpH4&feature=player_embedded)

Comment: I do work for a company that has a VPN in place so it will benefit me a lot :)

Comment: @Darius Nice, you're good to go then! This App will secure your connection every time, provided you authenticate at your company :) **ps:** I had to mention *"One thing that's not clear..."* part to be sure ;)

Comment: I should have checked before but I know now that the app in question works with Cisco implementation of VPN only.

Comment: @Darius Yes, you are correct. It is a Cisco Solution for Cisco Implementations :)